# Cannot pass param behind equals to zsh alias

Tags: zsh

I am trying to setup an alias where I can pass a parameter behind equals sign, i.e.

```
sfdx force:config:set defaultusername=foo
```

I have tried few ways, for example this

```
alias dxd='sfdx force:config:set defaultusername={$1}'
alias dxd='sfdx force:config:set defaultusername='
alias dxd='sfdx force:config:set defaultusername=$1'
```

But it always get an error:

```
ERROR:  Setting variables must be in the format <key>=<value> or <key>="<value with spaces>" but found master.
```

I am assume there is a space added after equals, resulting something like this:

```
sfdx force:config:set defaultusername= foo
```

I guess there's something special about how zsh threats params?

The intended syntax is `dxd foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliases won't accept arguments; only functions do.  For your case this
should work:

```
dxd() { sfdx force:config:set defaultusername=$1 }
```

Then invoke it as you've specified:

```
dxd foo
```

Comment: Thanks, you are star cat!